# Язык C, преобразование unsigned -> signed

Tags: c

Согласно Стандарту, переполнение знакового есть неопределенное поведение...

Значит ли это, что классический случай:

```
unsigned int ui = UINT_MAX - rand() % 10;
signed int si = ui;
```

Является неопределенным поведением?

Где можно найти как можно более полный перечень ситуаций, в которых возможно UB? Пускай и общее описание, без досконального разбора каждого случая.

Comment: Можно поискать https://teccxx.neocities.org/mx1/ub.html

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно интересная информация.

Comment: Но там нет ответа на мой вопрос, к сожалению.

Comment: Конкретно про переполнение: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), раздел 'Риски для безопасности'. Если не пугает английский - там есть ссылки на англоязычные ресурсы

Comment: @acade По ссылке автор игнорирует различия между С и С++ и пишет так, как будто ситуация одинакова в обоих языках. А это не так. Например, просто забыть вернуть значение из функции - сразу UB в С++, но не в С. В С это UB только если вызывающий код попытается воспользоваться возвращенным значением.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переполнение при целочисленном *преобразовании* к знаковому типу не является неопределенным поведением. Результат при таком переполнении *определяется реализацией* или может привести к сигналу

> **6.3 Conversions**
>   **6.3.1 Arithmetic operands**
>   **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>   [...]
>   **3** Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

К неопределенному поведению приводит знаковое целочисленное переполнение при выполнении арифметических вычислений, но не при выполнении целочисленных преобразований.

---

Перечисление ситуаций, в которых возникает неопределенное поведение можно найти в конце стандарта языка, в приложении J. Раздел **J.2 Undefined behavior**.

Comment: Тут около двух сотен возможных ситуаций, в которых возникает неопределенное поведение! Это для C99. Но, насколько мне известно, нет компиляторов, которые бы на 100% поддерживали хотя бы один из Стандартов. Даже GCC и Clang имеют определенные оговорки и уточнения. Получается, что вообще не существует способа с уверенностью сказать, есть ли в программе UB или его там нет. Особенно в программе, которая содержит исходники, некоторые из которых писались еще во времена C89, а другие пишутся во времена C11. Это в самом деле так?

Comment: Особенно, если учесть, что есть моменты, которые в C89 являлись IB, а в C99/C11 стали UB. Какой ужас...